# Filter results of One to One Field in Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-models

First of all, here is the model that I'm trying to restrict:

Question class:

```
class Question(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(
    max_length = 200,
    verbose_name = "Question title")
description = models.TextField(
    verbose_name = "Question description")
block = models.ForeignKey(
    to=Block,
    null=True,
    on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    verbose_name='Subject part to which this question belongs')
timestamp = models.DateTimeField(
    auto_now_add=True,
    verbose_name='Date at which the question was added')
```

Poster class that contains the One to One field to Question that I want to restrict:

```
class Poster(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(
    max_length = 200,
    verbose_name = "The poster's title")
description = models.TextField(
    verbose_name = "The poster's description")
authors = models.CharField(
    max_length = 200,
    verbose_name = "Authors' names")
image = models.ImageField(
    upload_to = 'images',
    verbose_name = 'Poster image')
block = models.ForeignKey(
    to = Block,
    null = True,
    on_delete = models.SET_NULL,
    verbose_name = 'The subject part to which the poster belongs')
associated_question = models.OneToOneField(
    Question,
    null=True,
    blank=True,
    on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    unique=True,
    verbose_name='Question associated to this poster')
```

What I'm trying to do is restrict the options that the "associated_question" field shows in the admin. What I mean by that is that if for example, I just wanted to show in the admin the questions that had a timestamp over a certain limit, how would I do that?

Thank you very much in advance. If I missed something that is necessary to understand my question, please ask me for it. I'll be glad to give more information if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to limit list in admin by default you can override `get_queryset` and filter queryset, like that:

**EDIT:** to filter `associated_question` dropdown form field you can use [formfield_for_foreignkey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey)

```
class PosterAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(PosterAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        timestamp_limit = datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)
        return qs.filter(associated_question__timestamp__gt=timestamp_limit)

    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request=None, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "associated_question":
            timestamp_limit = datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)
            kwargs["queryset"] = Question.objects.filter(timestamp__gt=timestamp_limit)
        return super(PosterAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

Limit Questions list

```
class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(QuestionAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        timestamp_limit = datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)
        return qs.filter(timestamp__gt=timestamp_limit)
```

Comment: When I try to add a new poster, it still shows in the dropdown for associated_question all the questions that are in the database

Comment: If you want to limit list of questions shown in `Poster`'s form dropdown you can override `formfield_for_foreignkey` method on `ModelAdmin`, check out updated answer.